# Let $M$ be a metric space. If every continuous function $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has compact range then $M$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $M$ be a metric space. If every continuous function $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has compact range then $M$ is compact.

I got this question from "Real Mathematical Analysis" by Charles Chapman Pugh.
Specifically Exercise 118 in Chapter 2. I'm not sure how to go about proving this question, but it seems useful for another equivalence of what it means for a metric space to be compact.

EDIT: I don't see how this question is a duplicate of the other link in question. Or I at least don't understand how it is a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried reasoning by contradiction?

Comment: If there exists an injective function, you are done by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @Darkdub your first sentence is what you're trying to prove!

Comment: @TedShifrin I attempted it, but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stronger result is this: if every real continuous function on $M$ is bounded then $M$ is compact. To prove this suppose M is not compact. Then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of distinct points with no convergent subsequence. Let $A=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$. Then $A$ has no limit points in $M$ and hence it is closed. Define $f:A \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x_n)=n$. Then $f$ is continuous and Tietze Extension Theorem shows that this function can be extended to a continuous function $F$ on $M$. Clearly, $F$ is continuous but not bounded.

Comment: This is great! Thank you.